# Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am having an issue while deploying my site to `AWS`.

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.5.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
  /var/app/ondeck/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
  LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
  /var/app/ondeck/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

while when I do `gem list rake` it gives me

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

airbrake (4.3.1)
rake (10.5.0, 10.4.2)
```

I want to have just one version when I do `bundle exec gem uninstall rake -v 10.4.2` it gives me

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "rake" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

How to resolve this issue? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: prepend `bundle exec` to whatever command you ran to give the error, exactly as the error tells you to do.

Comment: I ran into this error when attempting to debug RoR on VSCode using WSL.  I fixed that issue by adding "useBundler":true to my launch.json.  VSCode throwing this error is how I ended up here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to prefix your command with `bundle exec`. For example, if your `rake` command is

```
rake deploy
```

You have instead to use

```
bundle exec rake deploy
```

Bundler will fetch the proper gem versions as listed in your `Gemfile`, and execute the command.

Comment: Please read my answer. As I wrote, just prepend your command with `bundle exec`.

Comment: You need to make sure that your command never calls any other subcommand directly.

Comment: how to make sure that?

Comment: You need to inspect your code to check if you are running any shell command, and always prepend it with `bundle exec`.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 31):

First run **bundle update rake** .

I hope this works for you.

Comment: It will not work if you don't use `bundle exec` for the subsequent commands.

Comment: this just solved the problem for me.  bundle exec is not necessary after running this update.